# jQuery UI Sortable performance while sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a calendar being used in production with 60 days and up to 5 sortable items per day, so that's 300 sortable items. The days are `<td>` elements and the events are `<div>`s.

Both sorting within a day and dragging from one day to another are slow. The element freezes up for a bit when it enters a new day or when it passes over another sortable item.

The delay seems related to both the number of days and the number of sortable items.

Here is the jQuery code.

```
$('.calendar-schedule-day').sortable({
    items: ".service-trip, .calendar-event",
    connectWith: ".calendar-schedule-day"
});
```

How can I reduce the delay that occurs when sorting?

**More info**

Where chrome is calling `Layout` and `RecalculateStyle` many times in a row, there is the following warning:

Layout - Details
Duration    15.000 ms (at 36.86 s)
Note    Forced synchronous layout is a possible performance bottleneck.
Layout invalidated
....

---

Update: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/LBvmj) - it is so unusably slow that I can't tell if it reproduces the problem or not. It is not like that in production. But if I start removing html (like weeks) from the example then I may not be able to reproduce the problem anyway.

Comment: Chrome's timeline inspector is showing that `Layout` and `RecalculateStyle` are being called about a hundred times in a row at the points mentioned above.

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/LBvmj @Dom the jsfiddle is so unusably slow that I can't tell if it reproduces the problem or not. It is not like that in production. But if I start removing html (like weeks) from the example then I may not be able to reproduce the problem anyway.

Comment: there is no reason for me to think it will even reproduce in jsfiddle

Comment: @Benjamin Post your code somewhere, even if it runs slow, we need to see the code. How about http://jsbin.com

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos Benjamin posted his code - it's the third comment up top. Anyway, I've updated his question with it to make it easier to find.

Comment: tinker.io is much quicker.. made one for u. http://tinker.io/7599f

Comment: @codelio your example doesn't work for me.

Comment: @p.kelly yes because i just startet a tinker and did not edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems i got it a lot faster by hiding all sortable elements before calling sortable and after it i show them again.

```
$('.calendar-schedule-day').hide();
$('.calendar-schedule-day').sortable({ ... });
$('.calendar-schedule-day').sortable({ connectWith: ... });
$('.calendar-schedule-day').show();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBvmj/4/)

**Better way to fix it**

just use this selector `$('.calendar-schedule-day:visible')` instead of `$('.calendar-schedule-day')` when using `.sortable()`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBvmj/5/)

Seems that the hide elements messes with sortable, so we will only make the visible elements sortable.

Comment: You dont show sundays so you will have to fix some stuff there, but i think this way you can improve the speed a lot.

Comment: Sweet, I think you did it. Just gotta do a little more testing here to confirm. This looks great so far.

Comment: Bernardo, thank you very much. It is definitely working smoothly in chrome now. I also checked in ie10 and it is lightning fast. Very cool. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, i dont know why yet but seems that those invisible objects being sortable were the problem.